# Hostapd *just* for SSH

Tags: wifi, ssh, ethernet, bridge

I have a WiFi-to-Ethernet bridge on my raspberry pi 4B that works great, but I’d like to be able to SSH into the unit when no network is detected. Is there a way to configure hostapd just so I can SSH? Whenever I setup a hotspot it works, but then messes up my Ethernet bridge. I only need the hotspot for ssh, internet connectivity is not required

Comment: You can not configure hostapd that way.  However, you can use iptables to block traffic.  You need to allow RELATED,ESTABLISHED traffic but after that you can block all the ports but 22 and possible 67/68 for DHCP client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had a similar issue where I wanted to make sure I could control the Raspberry Pi via my hotspot if like something goes wrong with it.  As far as I know, the Raspberry Pi should have its own IP address under the hotspot. It is normally the gateway or something. You should just be able to connect to the IP address just like that.

Another option that I did, I set up Cockpit or another service that can do SSH via the web. Doesn't need the internet, and you can do it via the web. You just connect to the hotspot and go to the IP and port of the Raspberry Pi and cockpit.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I’ll try cockpit